# Java - Stack Trace showing offending lines in code which isn't the same as original source code

Tags: java, stack-trace

I recently encountered an issue where my `NullPointerException` produced a stack trace - the offending lines in which don't match the source code used to compile the classes.

I can confirm 100% that the code is the same since all other signatures have matched for our code. It seems that the lines are off for the top 2-3 files - Others are okay.

I am not sure if this is a file line formatting issue or some configuration. But I would assume that the configuration-related problem should corrupt all line numbers not just a file or two.

Has anyone encountered this before?

By the way - I have recompiled in 2/3 different machine - no difference. I cannot share the source code since it's proprietary.

Comment: Did you clean the `target` folder and do a rebuild?

Comment: Paranoia: if the class contains a serialVersionUID change that. Expressions over several lines can skew the numbering. You also might have an EBCDIC NEL character U+85, but that is even less likely. A multiline comment with `\u000a` maybe. Often a build issue.

Comment: This is really odd - every time that I've seen a problem like this it has always pointed to a build issue. The only thing I could think about is inconsistent CR/LF sequences in some of your files, i.e. when text editor "sees" one end-of-line mark, while the compiler "sees" two marks, or vice versa.

Comment: Can you make a working example?  Is there anything being added/removed while building the files?

Comment: This can happen when the app is running a jar where the related source code was updated (perhaps just formatting).  Recompiling doesn't help since the app continues to use the old jar.  Try to clean/refresh the workspace.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight               It's Windows Server 2008

Comment: @phflack          I have been trying without using my original source code - but so far no luck. I did add logger into nested calls of different class method to keep tracking the execution as  a "workaround" but it seems that no matter how many times and clean package the code it doesn't avoid that mismatch :(. Don't know that kind of garbage eclipse editor is adding

Comment: Could you try feeding your suspicious source as an input to [this small Java program](https://ideone.com/Bzbfvq) on your local machine, and see what it prints?

Comment: Can you see how eclipse is building the files?  I'm curious if it's adding in things like package information, without it being present in your source files

Comment: I have simply copied-pasted the whole code into Notepad++ and checked using "Show all symbols" - for each line it is ending with CR-LF and any blank like has CR-LF.